# NO_AGENT_DETECTED opscenter

Tags: datastax

I have installed DSE 5.0.1 and Opscenter on an EC2 instance. My plan is to use Opscenter/LifeCycle Manager to provision additional nodes on EC2.

I can see the Opscenter GUI and I can connect to the cluster using cqlsh. However, when I check the Agents view, I get this error - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYW9G.jpg

I installed the datastax agent manually and I've also opened up the ports on the EC2 instance.

On clicking the agent, I get the following status.

127.0.0.1 Agent Status
{
  "rack": "rack1",
  "agent_status": {
    "storage_cassandra": {
      "updated_at": null,
      "last_up": 0,
      "status": "unknown"
    },
    "last_seen": null,
    "version": null,
    "condition": "NO_AGENT_DETECTED",
    "install_status": {
      "error-message": null,
      "state": null
    },
    "jmx": {
      "updated_at": null,
      "last_up": 0,
      "status": "unknown"
    },
    "monitored_cassandra": {
      "updated_at": null,
      "last_up": 0,
      "status": "unknown"
    },
    "http": {
      "failure_reason": "An error occurred while connecting: 107: Transport endpoint is not connected.",
      "updated_at": 1469465897,
      "last_up": 0,
      "status": "down"
    },
    "stomp": {
      "updated_at": null,
      "last_up": 0,
      "status": "unknown"
    }
  },
  "name": "127.0.0.1",
  "agent_install_type": null,
  "dc": "Cassandra"
}

What could be wrong with my setup?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In the directory where you installed the opscenter (or unzipped it`s bin) there is a folder named conf.
In there create a file named address.yaml.
Edit the address.yaml and add the line :
    stomp_interface: "ip of the opscenter machine"

Also make sure the firewall is not blocking the agent`s connection port something like 61620/61621